# Returning multiple values using function causing multiple query runs

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have kiosks for customers to check their purchase volume for two different categories of items. They will input their mobile number, which will send an OTP to their mobile numbers and they will input it back to authenticate, the system has to check the data and display for them. As a developer, the kiosk supplier has provided us with a limited functionality development kit by which we can execute select statement on the database and display the returned values on the kiosk.

I have created an object type as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rebate_values
AS
   OBJECT (ASales_total number,
           ACurrent_Rebate_Percent number,
           ANeeded_Sales number,
           ANext_Rebate_Percent number,
           BSales_total number,
           BCurrent_Rebate_Percent number,
           BNeeded_Sales number,
           BNext_Rebate_Percent number);
```

A function to which I will pass customers' mobile to get their sales and rebate information:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AA_rebate_function (P_phone IN NUMBER)
   RETURN rebate_values
IS
   A_P_Sales_total              NUMBER;
   A_P_Current_Rebate_Percent   NUMBER;
   A_P_Needed_Sales             NUMBER;
   A_P_Next_Rebate_Percent      NUMBER;
   B_P_Sales_total              NUMBER;
   B_P_Current_Rebate_Percent   NUMBER;
   B_P_Needed_Sales             NUMBER;
   B_P_Next_Rebate_Percent      NUMBER;
   P_CODE                       VARCHAR (10);
BEGIN
   SELECT   CC_CODE
     INTO   P_CODE
     FROM   CUSTOMERS
    WHERE   C_MOBILE = P_phone;



   FOR OUTDATA
   IN (  

--My Query to retrieve the data
Select ................ 


)
   LOOP
      IF OUTDATA.CLASS = 'X'
      THEN
         A_P_Sales_total := OUTDATA.SALES_TOTAL;
         A_P_Current_Rebate_Percent := OUTDATA.CURRENT_REBATE_PERCENT;
         A_P_Needed_Sales := OUTDATA.NEEDED_SALES_FOR_HIGHER_REBATE;
         A_P_Next_Rebate_Percent := OUTDATA.NEXT_HIGHER_REBATE_PERCENT;
      END IF;


      IF OUTDATA.CLASS = 'Y'
      THEN
         B_P_Sales_total := OUTDATA.SALES_TOTAL;
         B_P_Current_Rebate_Percent := OUTDATA.CURRENT_REBATE_PERCENT;
         B_P_Needed_Sales := OUTDATA.NEEDED_SALES_FOR_HIGHER_REBATE;
         B_P_Next_Rebate_Percent := OUTDATA.NEXT_HIGHER_REBATE_PERCENT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;



   RETURN rebate_values (A_P_Sales_total,
                         A_P_Current_Rebate_Percent,
                         A_P_Needed_Sales,
                         A_P_Next_Rebate_Percent,
                         B_P_Sales_total,
                         B_P_Current_Rebate_Percent,
                         B_P_Needed_Sales,
                         B_P_Next_Rebate_Percent);
END;
/
```

The query takes 27 seconds to retrieve the values for each customer. Each customer will have 2 rows, so that's why I have used LOOP to collect the values.

When I execute the function:

```
SELECT   AA_rebate_function (XXXXXXXXXX) FROM DUAL;
```

I get data as follows in a single column within 27 seconds:

```
(XXXX, X, XXXX, X, XXXX, X, XXXX, X)
```

But when I execute the function to get the values in different columns, it takes 27 x 8 seconds = 216 seconds, i.e., approximately 3.6 minutes which is a big issue as the customer cannot wait for 3.6 minutes on the kiosk to view the data.

```
SELECT   x.c.ASales_total,
         x.c.ACurrent_Rebate_Percent,
         x.c.ANeeded_Sales,
         x.c.ANext_Rebate_Percent,
         x.c.BSales_total,
         x.c.BCurrent_Rebate_Percent,
         x.c.BNeeded_Sales,
         x.c.BNext_Rebate_Percent
  FROM   (SELECT   AA_rebate_function (XXXXXXXXXX) c FROM DUAL) x;
```

I have tried using stored procedure with `OUT` values but it doesn't fit in my environment as I cannot program to execute stored procedures from the kiosk development toolkit because it only supports select statements, checked with the supplier and they don't have any plan to add that support in near future.

I tried converting the single field into multiple columns using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` but I get a type conversion error as it is an array.

The query is very complex and has to calculate data for the last 10 years and has millions of rows, 27 seconds is actually the optimum time to get the desired results.

Comment: Simplify your problem down and create a mock-up that demonstrates the particular difficulties you're having.  That way you can include real code (instead of cutting bits out) and representative data (rather than making us guess).  See here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does it really have to calculate last 10 years at that time? Can't you have the value pre-calculated / summarized on level that would reduce the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I didn't realize that when you query a function that returns an object, it runs the function once for each column you reference the object in. That's awkward.

The easiest solution I could find for this is to switch your function to be PIPELINED. You'll need to create a nested table type to do this.

```
create type rebate_values_t is table of rebate_values;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AA_rebate_function (P_phone IN NUMBER)
  RETURN rebate_values_t PIPELINED
IS
  ... your code here ...
  PIPE ROW (rebate_values (A_P_Sales_total,
                     A_P_Current_Rebate_Percent,
                     A_P_Needed_Sales,
                     A_P_Next_Rebate_Percent,
                     B_P_Sales_total,
                     B_P_Current_Rebate_Percent,
                     B_P_Needed_Sales,
                     B_P_Next_Rebate_Percent));
  RETURN;
END;  
/

SELECT   x.ASales_total,
         x.ACurrent_Rebate_Percent,
         x.ANeeded_Sales,
         x.ANext_Rebate_Percent,
         x.BSales_total,
         x.BCurrent_Rebate_Percent,
         x.BNeeded_Sales,
         x.BNext_Rebate_Percent
  FROM   TABLE(AA_rebate_function (XXXXXXXXXX)) x;
```

For some reason, this should only execute the function once, and take 27 seconds.

Comment: thanks it took 27 seconds only to get the result. I will try to optimize the query further to reduce the runtime. Thanks again.